# Why is Fermat's last theorem important?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Could tell me someone why the solution for Fermat's last Theorem is important? Which impact does it have on other things?

For me the statement itself seems not so useful, but maybe there is a big Impact I don't know.

Comment: Understanding is rarely useless. Apart from anything else, it stimulates activity in other areas, elliptic curves, modular forms & Pokémon, for example.

Comment: It *is* useless ultimately, even in a pure context, but the machinery used to prove it is not.

Comment: It isn't. What was then called the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture is extremely important, though.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Not entirely useless, i am sure that Wiles's life is much improved as a result.

Comment: Why are these topics always tagget with Fermat Numbers?

Comment: I don't understand why some people are down voting this post. It's a legitimate question to ask. I can only recall the importance of Fermat's Last theorem is a historical one before the 80s, then after Ribet's Theorem people start to see the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often with very difficult problems like Fermat's last theorem, although it is nice to know the theorem is true, the methods used give a deep insight.